# Python: Using Asfreq and groupby

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following structures:

[image]

And I would like to transform into the following structures:

[image]

The idea is to break down the annual frequency into month-start frequency, and then ffill the value. But I encountered the ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis, since the date value is repeating.

Comment: can you share the data in raw format please, so that its easier to write the code

Comment: df=pd.DataFrame({'date':['2020-01-01','2021-01-01','2022-01-01','2023-01-01','2024-01-01','2020-01-01','2021-01-01','2022-01-01','2023-01-01','2024-01-01'],\
                 'item_code':['code_1','code_1','code_1','code_1','code_1','code_2','code_2','code_2','code_2','code_2'],\
                 'amount':[10,20,30,40,50,10,20,30,40,50]})

Comment: by what logic is the `amount` and `item_count` replicated

Comment: The key idea is to break down from annual frequency into monthly frequency, so between 2020-01-01 and 2021-01-01, there will be 12 rows replicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby("item_code").resample("M").ffill()
```

where you need to have "Date" as a datateime index.